# Python asyncio function does not run in parallel

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I have an asyncio code below. I expect it to run in parallel (print chunk_no's of all chunks first, then start to print 'processed' info), however it doesn't run in parallel. The output is this:

```
chunk_no: 0
Processed 0. item in chunk 0
Processed 1. item in chunk 0
Processed 2. item in chunk 0
...
chunk_no: 1
Processed 0. item in chunk 1
Processed 1. item in chunk 1
Processed 2. item in chunk 1
...
```

But I expect it to first print all 'chunk_no's. What's wrong with my code?

```
class Extractor:
    async def process_chunk(self, chunk_no,  chunk):
        print('chunk_no: ' + chunk_no)
        for i, seq in enumerate(chunk):
            counter = 0
            for j in range(i,1000000000):
                counter+=1
            print('Processed %d. item in chunk %d' % (i, chunk_no))

    async def run(self):
        ctx = Wtp()
        ctx.process("~/Dev/wikipedia/enwiki-latest-pages-articles15.xml-p17324603p17460152.bz2", page_handler)
    
        htmls = []
    
        self.thread_count = 256
        self.chunk_size = int(len(ctx.page_seq) / self.thread_count)
        tasks = []
        for i in range(0,self.thread_count):
            fromIndex = i * self.thread_count
            toIndex = i * self.thread_count + self.chunk_size if i * self.thread_count + self.chunk_size  < len(ctx.page_seq) else len(ctx.page_seq)
            chunk = ctx.page_seq[fromIndex:toIndex]

            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(
                self.process_chunk(i,chunk)))

         await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

      

async def main():
    extractor = Extractor()
    await extractor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: `process_chunk` needs to await something that yields control back to the event loop. Currently it’s a blocking call. Based on the name, it sounds like it’s more likely to be CPU-bound than I/O bound. You’d be better off using a ProcessPoolExecutor and possibly even using concurrent.futures instead of asyncio.

Comment: Thanks, concurrent.futures worked. Although I needed to use ThreadPoolExecutor instead regarding application details.

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor makes sense if your code is I/O-bound. Since your example code is CPU-bound, ProcessPoolExecutor likely makes more sense. If your actual code is I/O-bound, however, it would be good to update your example. There's a chance asyncio would be a better solution.